# My laptop connects and disconnects endlessly (without me being able to do anything about it) with a wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-11, internet-connection

My laptop has a WiFi problem (almost certainly a software problem) because as soon as it connects to a network where you have to log in to the browser, it keeps reconnecting and opening the login tab again and again.
The problem only occurs when I connect to a network where I have to log in via the browser. It is an internal Wi-Fi.
If I manage to log in within a few seconds, the connection is stable. My laptop is up to date (Windows 11) and I have already reset the network via the settings.
I have already updated the driver of the network adapter and also uninstalled and reinstalled it.

Comment: Does this happen with every Wi-Fi you try to connect to? Is this internal Wi-Fi or an external USB stick? Please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774267/edit) your question instead. That way it stays up-to-date, and all relevant info is readily available.

Comment: Try the [network troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-wi-fi-connection-issues-in-windows-9424a1f7-6a3b-65a6-4d78-7f07eee84d2c).

Comment: "My laptop has a WiFi problem (almost certainly a software problem) because as soon as it connects to a network where you have to log in to the browser, it keeps reconnecting and opening the login tab repeatedly." - This sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: Do you mean, "connect to a network where you have to log in **using** the browser,", as in some public WiFi spots, such as hotels, where the only access you have at first is to the hotel's home page, until *their* user name and password is entered?